# ObjectOutputSteam Sending Multiple Objects Before Receiving

Tags: java, oop, inputstream, outputstream

I am sending 2 objects using an `ObjectOutputSteam`. Can I send the second one before receiving the first one with an `ObjectInputStream`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is depends on how you do it.
But without details answer is: Yes, you can.